# Phonegap not rendering page after splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, xcode5, cordova-2.7.0

I have a phonegap application in the store which I had had to update recently. I made changes to only javascript and html file and tried to build again making changes to build setting so that I was able to build the application for iPhone 5s (64 bit). But now the problem is it runs with the new changes that I made in iPad (32 bit) but it does not display anything after splash screen in iPhone 5s. I can download and run the application from store in iPhone 5s which was build for previous versions of iPhone but when I build and run using Xcode; this problem appear.

If you have come across such problem; I would like  to kindly request your solution or suggestion.Thanks in advance

- Note: I am using the latest Xcode and phonegap 2.7.0

Comment: can u share the latest javascript code which u updated in the last version?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the javascript code that I updated. I just does not run even with the old code that I had.

Comment: Cordova/Phonegap 2.X version does not have support for 64bit. You will need to upgrade to 3.X (probably 3.2 at minimum, but recommend latest)

Comment: I have already found a way to support the 64 bit version for cordova by making a  new plugin. Thank you for your assistant.